# Sending JSON via ActiveMQ and Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, activemq-classic

I'm trying to send a JSON object via ActiveMQ. I've tried sending simple `String` via ActiveMQ and instead of `{"a":1}` i've got something like this: `{\"a\":1}\n". I know that it's a proper`String` format, but the gson has failed to deserialize the string back to object.

I have a listener like this:

```
    @JmsListener(destination = "requests.queue")
    @SendTo("responses.queue")
    public String onMessage(Message message) throws JMSException {
        String requestBody = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
        String response = myService(requestBody);
        return gson.toJson(response);
    }
```

This listener receives a request like `{"a":1}`, processes it via myService and push it back as a string. The only issue is that i'm unable to receive a proper JSON string.

I know that I can use methods like `replase()` and clean the string, but as for me it's a really bad solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Your response is of type String. How are you expecting GSON to serialize that for you?

Comment: Yep. 
For example. I have sent a request to ActiveMQ via web-interface `{"id":1, "type":1} and there was no problem handling the request. But in the response queue I've got something like this `{\"id\":2, \"type\":1}`. When I copied pasted the request queue, the GSON failed to convert the same request.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. What is the value of "response" before calling `gson.toJson(response)`?